# Get likes in one of my posts in my Instagram page

Tags: php, web-scraping, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I have a telegram bot written in PHP, to make my users link their telegram account to their Instagram account so I can get their Instagram id.

For this I use the Basic Display API of Instagram.

Now, I need to check if a user likes one of my posts or even if an user follows my page, when they do, so I need my bot to give them reward points.

The problem is that the Basic and Graph API doesn't provide such data and I really cannot do much, I don't know how some applications can do Giveaways and stuff like that.

I wanted to scrape the data with a PHP library for web scraping but I'm worried that I will violate the terms of Instagram and they could ban/shadow ban my account.

What can I do to prevent violating the terms? And what can I do to get the data I need?

Comment: _"What can I do to prevent violating the terms?"_ - Facebook's terms & conditions say scraping is only allowed if you had their explicit prior written approval, I'd guess for IG the rules are probably the same. Hard to imagine you would have any chance to get that though - without any offense, you are probably simply way "too small" to be even considered for anything like that. There isn't even an official, documented way to request this, to my knowledge.

Comment: Plus, if Facebook wanted you to get access to this data and would approve of this kind of use case, they would probably have provided access via the API in the first place.

Comment: I see, I had to make this application for a company so I will find a workaround, maybe I will just use the comments. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: Facebook explicitly forbids rewarding users for liking a page or posts, I wouldn't be surprised if the same thing was true for Instagram.